# Code not executing when referred to in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am using geoip-db.com to identify the general location a user. My code works on its own, however im facing a bit of difficulty integrating it with my other code.

I am using the following bit of code to identify the location:

```js
var country = document.getElementById('country');
var state = document.getElementById('state');
var city = document.getElementById('city');
var postal = document.getElementById('postal');
var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
var ip = document.getElementById('ipv4');

function callback(data) {
  country.innerHTML = data.country_name;
  state.innerHTML = data.state;
  city.innerHTML = data.city;
  postal.innerHTML = data.postal;
  latitude.innerHTML = data.latitude;
  longitude.innerHTML = data.longitude;
  ip.innerHTML = data.IPv4;
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(script, h);
```

```html
<div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>
<div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
<div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
<div>Postal: <span id="postal"></span></div>
<div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
<div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
<div>IP address: <span id="ipv4"></span></div>
```

I would like the output to be through the following code (We will call this code A):

```js
case 'send end':
  if (connect === 1) {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Country: <span id="country"></span></div><div>State: <span id="state"></span></div><div>City: <span id="city"></span></div><div>Postal: <span id="postal"></span></div><div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div><div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div><div>IP address: <span id="ipv4"></span></div><span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
  } else {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Failed<span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
  }
  break;
```

However it does not seem to work! The output is as follows:

Country:

State:

City:

Postal:

Latitude:

Longitude:

IP address:

*The lables are shown however the results are not..

Comment: Any errors displayed in browser dev tools console?

Comment: There are no errors displayed in the browser dev  tools console

Comment: You are using `switch` right?

Comment: Im not sure what switch is..

Comment: You've got a `case` there but it's not in a `switch` block. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct fix for Code A (I'm not sure what the event would be called in this situation, so I called it event):

```
function functionName (event) {
   switch (event) {
      case 'send end':
         if (connect === 1) {
            $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Country: <span id="country"></span></div><div>State: <span id="state"></span></div><div>City: <span id="city"></span></div><div>Postal: <span id="postal"></span></div><div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div><div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div><div>IP address: <span id="ipv4"></span></div><span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
         } else {
            $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Failed<span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
         }
      break;
      default:
          //This is recommended but not necessary
   }
}
```